# How to automate data insertion on Excel?

Tags: excel

I need control my job time on a Excel sheet. I've two data: Datetime and action (arrive and exit).

For example:

```
2019-04-22  Arrived   Exit
           09:00 APM  01:00 PM


2019-04-23  Arrived   Exit
           09:30 APM  02:00 PM
```

My idea is has two buttons to insert the data, so when I click on 'Arrive' (for example) the Excel creates a new line and auto insert Datetime and action. How I can do it on Excel online?

Answer (score 0):

Put a command button on your sheet and code it.
Use the Now() method on each button.

Comment: For me `=now()` is returning `########`

Comment: You will need to have your developer tab enabled on your ribbon. Go to settings and edit your ribbon, once you have done that then you will see there is a INSERT button on the DEVELOPER tab. Insert a command button but then you will need to code the button, I am assuming you dont know how to open the VBE and add code?